# The employer is taking a long time to respond?

Tags: hiring, process

I went for the interview at a police dispatch job in November of 2018 and heard back from them in the beginning of December they were consider a different applicant and will give them a reasonable amount of time, four days preferably. I have called back in the beginning of January because I have not heard anything back and they told me the applicant refused but are waiting for HR to send them more applicants and will restart the interview process. My question is how long I should wait for this job to decide? I have called once and at the end of the January just to see the status of my applications and no one is sure what is going on.

Comment: Exactly what is it that you are waiting for?

Comment: If they are "waiting for HR to send them more applicants and will restart the interview process", then you have your response - you're not getting that job.

Comment: I've once applied to a job and was only called for an interview more than 6 months later. Specially for not-so-small companies, hiring processes may be very slow. but then again, if you want a follow-up just because you are curious, then there is no need to bother the company. You should warn them if you are considering another proposal while waiting for theirs.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is how long I should wait for this job to decide?

Since it is government related, it might not be hopeless - they can have weird rules which are inflexible.
But as Joe Strazzere wrote in a comment, "The outlook for this one isn't good."

Wait no longer.  Get on with your life.

If they call you back, great!

If they don't... I'm sorry to break it to you, but that's what I expect will happen.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is ask for updates and wait and see if they decide to respond.

But until you have signed contracts and have actually started the job, there is no reason to stop searching. There's no sense in pinning all your hopes on one company which hasn't committed to anything.